# Need help to use resource manager to load an image from resource with same name as text in textBox

Tags: c#, string, image, resources, resourcemanager

I need to load an image from resources with same name as text in a textBox. I have 2 problems with my actual code:

-The name 'Assembly' doesn't exist in the context

-I don't know how to use my string (index1) to add image from resources to a list.

This is my actual code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Resources;

namespace Booster_pack_2
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Image> Images1 = new List<Image>();
            ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("ResourceReader.MyResource", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            string index1 = textBox1.Text;
            pictureBox1.Image = rm.GetObject(index1) as Image;
            Images1.Add(Booster_pack_2.Properties.Resources.index1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `using System.Reflection;` needed for `Assembly`

Comment: Thanks for this. But how to add the Image to a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `System.Reflection` in your code to use the `Assembly` class as suggested by addy2012. As for the list, `Properties.Resources` has a static `ResourceManager` in it, use that.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Image> Images1 = new List<Image>();
    ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("ResourceReader.MyResource", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    string index1 = textBox1.Text;
    pictureBox1.Image = rm.GetObject(index1) as Image;
    Images1.Add((Image)Booster_pack_2.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(index1));
}
```

If both images are the same, you should assign the image to a local variable and use that. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Is it normal to get : 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll?